# Having trouble writing a WebSocket server and client

Tags: javascript, node.js, dataframe, sockets, websocket

I'm trying to write a WebSocket server in NodeJS that functions as a very basic chatting app where users can send either text or images. The system I have created to process data frames sent by the client (Firefox) falls apart when messages with a payload over 65536 bytes are sent, these messages are sent to the server over a fragmented message that doesn't seem to follow the websocket standard. According to the [RFC WebSocket Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.4), in order for client data frames to be interpreted by the server to be a fragmented message the very first bit (FIN) must be 0 and the 4th to 8th bits (opcode) must be 0000 along with the necessary masking and initial payload data. However, in my experience Firefox will send a message of over 65536 bytes as 3 frames.

1. Frame 1:

   - A set FIN bit, indicating that this is the last frame of this message
   - Opcode bits indicating that this is a normal text or binary frame, not a continuation frame
   - Masking bit set and payload size indicator being correct
   - Actual payload size, which is consistent with the message I'm attempting to send
   - Masking key
   - No payload data
2. Frames 2 and 3:

   - Array of bytes, the amount of bytes is the expected payload length

It is entirely possible that I am misinterpreting the RFC WebSocket Standard document, however it seems that when I call the function to send data to the websocket:

```
webSocket.send([string over 65536 characters])
```

This is an accurate output of my function:

```
socket.on('readable', (req, socket, head) => {
    const { data } = socket.read().toJSON()
    console.log(data)
})

[ 129, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 17, 112, 116, 104, 111, 235 ]
[ 2, 28,  0, 142,  4, 14, 28, 133, 30, 13, 14, ... ]
[ 22, 5, 2, 153, 31, 29, 31, 129, 1, 28,  2, ... ]
```

As you can see, the first byte of the first frame can be represented in binary as 10000001 in which the FIN bit is set and the opcode indicates a standard text frame.

So I'm not entirely sure what's going on, I doubt that either the RFC WebSocket documentation or Firefox are incorrect but I can't seem to get a response that I can predict on the backend. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not fully sure about your question. But it looks like you attempt to read a Websocket using plain TCP sockets and then expect a single Websocket message to result in a single TCP socket read. This assumption is wrong: TCP is a byte stream only and a single Websocket message can be delivered over multiple socket reads.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am not familiar with TCP, that would probably be a good place to start, thank you.

Comment: @Avvy there's a reason why websocket message contains its own payload length. And theres a reason why it comes before the payload. You have to read it (it always comes at fixed offset if I remember correctly) and then keep reading (in a loop) until you read that many bytes. Only then you will read a single websocket message. With sizes over 64kb it is very likely that fragmentation happens on TCP/IP level. Meaning it still is a single websocket message, but you need multiple read calls to fully read it. Reading raw websocket messages is not trivial.

Comment: @freakish that makes a lot of sense, so I assume the other 2 frames the server is receiving should be the actual payload. And its not necessarily a fragmented message either?

Comment: @Avvy correct. Of course we won't know for sure until you implement and test it properly.